# Add a select material-ui in react

Tags: ecmascript-6, reactjs, material-ui

I guys i'm doing an appp in material ui:

```
import React from 'react';
//Import statement:
import TextField from 'material-ui/lib/text-field';
import TimePicker from 'material-ui/lib/time-picker';
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/lib/date-picker/date-picker';
import SelectField from 'material-ui/lib/select-field';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/lib/menus/menu-item';

const containerStyle = {
  textAlign: 'center',
  paddingTop: 200,
};

const Main = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
      return(
        <div>
        <CitySearch/>
        <CourseSelector/>
        <Dater/>
        <Matiere/>
        </div>
        );
    }
});

var CitySearch = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Où ?</h1>
        <TextField
  hintText="Lieux" />
      </div>
      );
  }
});

var CourseSelector = React.createClass({

    render: function(){
      return(
          <div>
            <h1>Quand ?</h1>
            <TimePicker
  format="24hr"
  hintText="Début RDV" />
          </div>
        );
    }
});


var Dater = React.createClass({

    render: function(){
      return(
          <div>
            <h1>Quand mois ?</h1>
            <DatePicker
      hintText="Portrait Dialog" />
          </div>
        );
    }
});

var Matiere = React.createClass({

    render: function(){
      return(
          <div>
            <h1>Quand mois ?</h1>
            <SelectField value={1} disabled={false}>
    <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Matière"/>
    <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Français"/>
    <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Allemand"/>
    <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="Maths"/>
    <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="Anglais"/>
    <MenuItem value={6} primaryText="Chimie"/>
  </SelectField>
          </div>
        );
    }
});

export default Main;
```

and i'd like to add a select component the proble is that it uses exports and heritage and i don't know how to put the example code into my components.Here i got the code for select http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field

```
import React from 'react';
import SelectField from 'material-ui/lib/select-field';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/lib/menus/menu-item';

export default class SelectorSubject extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 2};
  }

  handleChange = (event, index, value) => this.setState({value});

  render() {
    return (
      <SelectField value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Maths"/>
        <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Anglais"/>
        <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Chimie"/>
        <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="Physique"/>
        <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="Allemand"/>
      </SelectField>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot mates

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: The code i pasted works fine but when i try to add the selector it got a problem with handleChange = (event, index, value) => this.setState({value}); i think it's an obsolete syntax? what do you think ?

Comment: The problematic code you just mentioned is not referenced in the issue description. I'd suggest updating the issue with code that contains the problem

Comment: @lux thank you I've updated with the selector code that i'm sensed to import in main

Comment: Ah, so using "this" in es6 classes are bit different than es5. That is `React.createClass` = es5, and `extends React.Component` = es6. You can use both, but check out the `lexical this` section of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: you'll need something like `onChange={() => this.handleChange(index)}` since by default `this` is not bound to your render function, as such you'll need to access `this` via an arrow function. Again, check out the doc I referenced

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you used this kind of bind notacion:

```
 handleChange = (event, index, value) => this.setState({value});
```

You must enable transform-class-properties or enable stage-2 in Babel. Here is the link hope this help you... 
[enter link description here](https://medium.com/@housecor/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56#.dwadsfsi9)